# ListView with mixed sources

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to have a `ListView` that draws from multiple sources? I want to have some hard-coded items and items from a `ContentProvider` in the same list, and I just want to know if that's possible.

Comment: If you have a way of determining which type of item to use, yes.

Comment: use a `[Simple]CursorAdapter` which uses a `MergeCursor` for example where some data comes from a `MatrixCursor` and some from your `ContentProvider`

Answer (score 1):

You could have both types of items implement an interface such as

```
public interface Item {
    int TYPE_1 = 1;
    int TYPE_2 = 2;
    int getViewType();
    View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
}
```

Then your `Adapter` can be for a list of `Item`s. Also, if you're unfamiliar with the View Holder pattern I'd recommend looking it up. A quick search revealed a pretty good looking example [here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

Answer (score 0):

You can let them extends a common parent class, and then use it to construct the adapter. I have done this before, I hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

So, I realized that

- I don't care if `ContentProvider` data is updated after the fragment loads and
- I want to do manipulations on the data in my list that I do not want reflected in the `ContentProvider`.

So I'm going to dump my cursor results into an `ArrayList` along with my hardcoded items, and I think that should work fine.